# Java JNI and dependent libraries on Windows

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java.library.path

Long story short: I have an executable jar, that calls `jni.dll` which is dependent on `lib.dll`. And I'm getting the oh-so-dreaded `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092576/95656) answer comes pretty close, yet it fails to solve the problem, from my experience. Even when the folder where the dll's reside is specified in `java.library.path`, it will not work. I have to change the Windows `PATH` environment variable as well. In fact, the default `java.library.path` on Windows seems to be `PATH`.

Is there any "pretty" way to fix this? I want to build an installer for Windows and I'm wondering how I would deal with this issue, so that the end-user will not have to do any manual work.

**EDIT:**

What I implemented is the following: the application ships with a folder called "native_libs" which has dynamic libraries for all supported architectures. The structure is the following:

```
/
+- native_libs/
   +- windows/
   |  +- x86/
   |  |  +- ...
   |  +- x64/
   |     +- ...
   |
   +- linux/
   |  +- x86/
   |  |  +- ...
   |  +- x64/
   |     +- ...
   |
   +- libs/
      +- ...
```

On runtime, while the application initializes, the correct JRE architecture and System OS are detected and the proper library files are copied to the libs/ folder. The `java.library.path` is being set on runtime as well using a common hack. Finally, the `PATH` environment variable for windows is set using a native launcher.

Any room for improvement? Maybe copying the dll's in the same directory as the `jar` file would negate the need for setting the `java.library.path` and `PATH` variables? I need to investigate loading the dll's with `System.load()` as well, which will negate the need to copy files.

Comment: Is there something else written for this error? Like "Could not find dependend libraries" or something similar?

Comment: Exactly that. I think I engineered a solution which is pretty dumb, but works and is at least transparent to the user. I will share once I'm sure that it works.

Comment: You can try to use the Dependency Walker to see what libraries are missing: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: "Preloading" DLLs with `System.load()` does work on Windows, unless there's a circular dependency between your DLLs. Is there a circular dependency between `jni.dll` and `lib.dll`?

Comment: @SamuelAudet No there isn't a circular dependency, check my comment below.

Answer (score 12):

`java.library.path` specifies the directories where `System.loadLibrary()` looks for the dynamic library file. If you change the `java.library.path` system property in your code, it will not have any effect. There are hacks to make Java "forget" the initial value and re-evaluate the contents of the `java.library.path` system property.

However, the dependent library is not loaded by Java, it's loaded by Windows. Windows does not care about `java.library.path`, it only cares about the `PATH` environment variable. Your only option is to adjust `PATH` for your Java process. For example, if you start it from a batch file, change the `PATH` environment variable right before the java invocation.

Comment: I understand the whole concept, what I'm asking for is for a way to do fix this "pretty", as I mentioned. And running a batch file is not "pretty", unfortunately. Do you have any other ideas? (by the way, when PATH has "." in it, should it be able to find the dependent dll? because apparently it does not).

and yes, I've used such a hack to make sure that the proper JNI is loaded according to the OS / JRE arch

Comment: You cannot adjust environment variables in a running process. "." will work if the current directory contains the dependent library. I would recommend to use a native launcher generator, most of them allow you to adjust the native library path.

Comment: As for the hack, the main point of my answer was to explain why this would not work for dependent libraries.

Comment: upvoted for clarifying the way the whole thing works for anyone interested -- "native launcher generator" was a perfect term to google, thanks!

Comment: @IngoKegel I agree that Windows should use the %PATH% to load the `dependent library`. But in my scenario, I put the folder containing the `dependent DLL` into the %PATH% but the DLL still cannot be found. **But it works if I place the dependent DLL into the JDK's bin folder**. Thus some of my team members have blindly put all DLLs into the JDK's bin folder, which I think is a mess. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891114/must-i-place-all-dependent-dlls-into-the-jdks-bin-folder  Appreciate if you can drop by.

Comment: @IngoKegel And I accidentally found that, user variable %PATH% doesn't work. System variable %PATH% works.

Comment: @IngoKegel I have found the root cause of my issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't figure this out, but adding the bin path to $Path$ in my debug configuration worked wonders.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to ensure that all .dlls are in '.' when you execute.

Comment: I need to check that. Are you sure that Windows will always look in "." for dll's?

Comment: Yes, it's a backwards compatibility issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/10/10088566.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the os can not find the dependency library, have you tried loading it via `System.loadLibrary()` before you load your main library?

Comment: @alkar: if nothing works, there's `System.load()` which takes a complete file path to the dll.

Comment: @alkar: also, post a complete stacktrace, please.

Comment: @EJP: nowhere in the javadoc of these methods does it say to load only jni libraries. See answers like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906862/143585 where people actually managed to make it work by loading dependencies before the main library.

Comment: @alkar and EJP: Yes it works. I should know, I use that hack on Windows all the time. Something _else_ may be wrong with your code.

Comment: @SamuelAudet: yes, it should work according to google, it must be that i failed the two runtime dependencies of lib.dll

Answer (score 0):

Put dlls your jni.dll depends on in your "current working directory", check this `System.getProperty("user.dir")` at runtime to get to know what is your "current working directory"